# Adding Save to PDF Based on Date and Content in Word

Tags: activex, cpu-word, contentcontrol

I have a word document created as a shift checklist for staff. The staff I'm dealing with isn't exactly up with technology, so the end game here is ease of use. The form is currently comprised of some Date Pickers and drop down list content controls.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Set a simple Active X button as "Submit Form"
- When Pressed, the file uses the date picker and drop down content control to format the file name as "Checklist *date shift name* " or some variation.
- Saved as a PDF to a shared drive, I can correct the file path later.
- Prefer to have the PDF open after save, sort of as a confirmation the action was completed.

I've tried some simple ones found here on stack, and found others that seem to be geared toward excel. But I'm having trouble implementing all the features.

Thanks in Advance!

Edit:

This is the code I found and tried. I'm not sure how to modify the file name using inputs or the path

```vb
Sub Convert_PDF()

 Dim desktoploc As String
 Dim filename As String
 Dim mypath As String

    desktoploc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    filename = ThisDocument.Name
    mypath = desktoploc & "\" & filename

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        mypath, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that there are two ContentControls.

One with a tag named "Date", one with a tag named "Shiftname"

Be aware that CC-tags are case-sensitive.

patternFilename: [date] and [shiftname] will be replaced according to the CC-values

```vb
Option Explicit

'this goes into the Thisdocument-module

'adjust these consts to your needs
Private Const pathForReports As String = "D:\"
Private Const patternFilename As String = "Checklist [date] [shiftname].pdf"

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
'ActiveX-Button on doc

    saveAsPdf

End Sub


Private Sub saveAsPdf()

Dim Fullfilename As String
Fullfilename = getFilename

ThisDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        Fullfilename, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument
End Sub

Private Function getFilename() As String

Dim strName As String
strName = patternFilename

strName = Replace(strName, "[date]", Format(getValueForCC("Date"), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
strName = Replace(strName, "[shiftname]", getValueForCC("Shiftname"))

getFilename = pathForReports & strName
End Function


Private Function getValueForCC(ccTag As String) As Variant
getValueForCC = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccTag)(1).Range.Text
End Function
```

Add an ActiveX Button to the document, right click on it, choose properties and rename it to "cmdSubmit":
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It will run in manually, I can't figure out how to run it with the button. What should the button be named?